# Unable to run assembly program

Tags: assembly, nasm, x86

I have just started reading Introduction to 80x86 Assembly Language and Computer Architecture.I am trying to use NASM, to run the first example shown in chapter 3 ,but unsuccessfully.Has anyone read the book,and run the examples?

Comment: What problems have you encountered? Are you unable to build the examples at the first place or do they simply don't run on your machine?

Comment: Why don't you post the code you are trying to run, and the compiler you are using?

Answer (score 3):

According to Google Books, you should be using [MASM](http://www.masm32.com/), not NASM. Try that.

For reference guys, page 47 [here](http://books.google.co.nz/books?id=TFw5vo-2ZYwC&dq=Introduction+to+80x86+Assembly+Language+and+Computer+Architecture&pg=PP1&ots=Q6BlvMLErg&sig=7mUshrWDXlJOZO5yhuB4CrKUZvA&hl=en&sa=X&oi=book_result&resnum=4&ct=result#PPA47,M1).

Answer (score 0):

I prefer NASM over MASM. There are significant [differences](http://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc2.html#section-2.2) between them, especially when it comes to things like variables and procedures (they are not really part of the NASM approach). You'll have to make up your own mind about which to use.